# Jypyter Notebook kernel dies when I run cursor.fetch_pandas_all()

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Whenever I try to read data from snowflake to a pandas dataframe using fetch_pandas_all(), the jupyter notebook kernel dies

Any solution to this?

Comment: When attempting the same scenario (a simple select) from SageMaker, it hangs, whereas the `write_pandas()` worked.
I ended up reading via pyspark, then converting to pandas.

Answer (score -1):

I'd strongly recommend you login to the Snowflake User Interface (I call it the webUI), navigate to the query history tab and review the query that Snowflake is receiving from your notebook.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html

Once you find the query that might be hanging, you can review the query profile to determine what query "nodes" are taking the longest, and then you can begin troubleshooting from there.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html#viewing-query-profile

You could (and probably should) [also increase your logging](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/logging.html) in python to determine if it's a Python issue, I haven't tried it yet, but this newer logging library looks promising.

https://towardsdatascience.com/introducing-pandas-log-3240a5e57e21

Comment: The fetch_pandas_all() runs after query has completed.